# How to resolve "The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing."

Tags: docker, npm, gitlab-ci, cypress

I'm trying to download and install Cypress within GitLab CI runner and getting this error output:

```
The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing.
We expected the binary to be installed here: /root/.cache/Cypress/4.8.0/Cypress/Cypress
Reasons it may be missing:
- You're caching 'node_modules' but are not caching this path: /root/.cache/Cypress
- You ran 'npm install' at an earlier build step but did not persist: /root/.cache/Cypress
Properly caching the binary will fix this error and avoid downloading and unzipping Cypress.
Alternatively, you can run 'cypress install' to download the binary again.
```

I ran the suggested command `cypress install` but it didn't help.
Next it says `You're caching 'node_modules' but are not caching this path: /root/.cache/Cypress`
I don't understand how you can cache the modules and leave out the path to it.
Next is `You ran 'npm install' at an earlier build step but did not persist` I did have `npm install` in earlier builds so I replaced it with `npm ci` as it's recommended in Cypress official docs in such cases.

No resolution though.

Here are relevant lines where the error occurs:

inside of Dockerfile:

```
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app/package-lock.json
RUN npm ci
```

inside the test runner:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml up -d --build
./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --config baseUrl=http://localhost
```

inside the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "flask-on-docker",
  "dependencies": {
    "cypress": "^4.8.0"
  }
}
```

Can anyone point me in a right direction ?

Answer (score 16):

You probably are running `npm install` and `cypress run` in two different stages. In this case, cypress cache could not be persisted, So it is recommended to use `CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER` option while running `install` and as well as `cypress run/open`. The command will looks like this,

```
CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER=./tmp/Cypress yarn install

CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER=./tmp/Cypress npx cy run [--params]
```

Comment: For Gitlab see https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/gitlab-ci#Testing-in-Chrome-and-Firefox-with-Cypress-Docker-Images

Answer (score 10):

This helped me (Windows):

```
.\node_modules\.bin\cypress.cmd install --force
```

Or if you're using a UNIX system:

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress install --force
```

https://newbedev.com/the-cypress-npm-package-is-installed-but-the-cypress-binary-is-missing-591-code-example

Answer (score 0):

`yarn cypress install --force` before running of tests worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
I run this code to grant jenkins user to be the owner of my cypress project folder
and after that everything was ok.

sudo chown -R jenkins: /your cypress project path/