# Cypress binary is missing and Gitlab CI pipeline

Tags: cypress, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to integrate cypress testing into gitlab pipeline.

I've tried about 10 different configurations which all fail.. I've included what I think are the relevant portions of of the gitlab.yml file, as well as the screenshot of the error on gitlab.

Thanks for any help

```
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

cache:
  paths:
    - src/ui/node_modules/
    - /root/.cache/Cypress/    //added this, also have tried src/ui/cypress/

build_ui:
  image: node:16.14.2
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd src/ui
    - yarn install --pure-lockfile --prefer-offline --cache-folder .yarn


ui_test:
  image: node:16.14.2
  stage: test
  needs: [build_ui]
  script:
    - cd src/ui
    - yarn run runCypressHeadless
```

[image: error msg]

Comment: Hi. This post might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62319657/how-to-resolve-the-cypress-npm-package-is-installed-but-the-cypress-binary-is

Answer (score 3):

Each job gets its own separate environment. Therefore, you need to install your dependencies in each job. Add your `yarn install` command to the `ui_test` job.

The reason why your `cache:` did not restore to the job from the previous stage is because caches are per job by default (e.g. caches are restored from previous pipelines that ran the same job). If you want subsequent jobs in the same pipeline to use the cache, [set the `cache:key:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#cachekey) to something like `$CI_COMMIT_SHA` or use [`cache:key:files:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#cachekeyfiles) to use a file key, like your lockfile(s).

Also, you [can only cache paths in the workspace](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#cachepaths). So you won't be able to cache/restore `/root/.cache/...` -- instead you should change the cache location to somewhere in the workspace.

For additional reference, see: [caching in GitLab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/) and [caching NodeJS dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#cache-nodejs-dependencies).